# rendering views dynamically on EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I just having a little trouble to implement a special kind of view for Ember, I'm digging on the source for days but can't find how to make it work... Can you take a look and tell me what's wrong? It's a small code, a specific problem when rendering one view from another (it's not doing the binds right...).

The sample code (with comments) that demonstrate the problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/wilkerlucio/rUUuN/

Edit:

Just to clarify, I'm trying to do a view that dynamically render another view. It can be useful for a lot of implementations, like tabs for example. On tabs you have the tabs and the container that shows current tab, so, the view that I'm trying to accomplish is like this current tab container. Each tab has it own view, and I need that my view be able to render the view for the current tab.

I know I can do things like just hide a view and show the other, but it's not the way I want it right now. This CardView that I'm creating should have a binding to a property that will return a view instance, and the CardView will render this view, and will update if the property that points the view updates.

You can see a more full covered example about what I'm trying to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/wilkerlucio/Ztdpb/

Thanks

Comment: It would be useful to know a bit more about what you're trying to achieve. I suspect there may be a better approach to what you're trying to do.

Comment: another thing that I noticed. If I used this.appendChild to add new view on render process, it works. But it's kinda flick when you update the internal view, it's like it removes and add's new view as separated steps, and you can see on the window it flicking... I'm trying to realize what is so different about adding a child view.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you need to specify the template as such:

```
App.CardView = Ember.View.extend({
    defaultTemplate: SC.Handlebars.compile('{{App.obj.value}}')
});
```

or

```
App.CardView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'sample'
});
```

If you are planning to have many child views, then you may want to try to use a collection view.

This link is a bit old, but it is still not bad: http://guides.sproutcore20.com/using_handlebars.html

I've also blogged about how it implemented CRUD operations with Ember (SC2) [here](http://blog.chililog.org/2011/11/02/sproutcore-v2-crud-tutorial-part-1/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second one is more correct. You don't need a nested view, so don't bother making one. You can attach a template to a view by using templateName.

Comment: Hi Veebs, thanks for the reply but this is not what I'm looking for... In fact there will be only one "child", but it will changes on runtime. It's like a layout changer, and at any point someone can change a binding that should refresh the view with a new view. The instantiation of subview is important, because the current subview will have it's own data. I have another class that acts as a router, so, user call's the router to change the "page", the CardLayout is supposed to be the "page" itself in this case (but the general purpose is that you can have many CardViews as you want).

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/wilkerlucio/Ztdpb/ for better full understanding of what I'm doing. Thanks

Comment: @YehudaKatz, in fact for what I wanna do I need a nested view... Please check the edit on text for more details.