# Ember.js view for object

Tags: templates, view, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have simple view in my Ember.js application, like this. Each "content" element consists of two objects, first and second:

```
{{#each App.myController.content}}
    {{view for content.first}}
    {{view for content.second}}
{{/each}}
```

I'd like to define view for each content separately (so as not to have to write it twice), in another handlebars template script. How can I pass the first and second variables to the view?

---

Here is a code sample, see http://jsfiddle.net/Zm4Xg/5/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contact-view">
     <div>{{name}}</div>
     <img {{bindAttr src="avatar"}} {{bindAttr alt="name"}}>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#each App.contactsController.pair}}
    <div class="menu_vertical_group">
      {{#with this.first}}
         {{view App.contactView}}
      {{/with}}

      {{#with this.second}}
         {{view App.contactView}}
      {{/with}}

    </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

**​JavaScript**:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Contact = Em.Object.extend({
    name: null,
    avatar: null
});

App.contactView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'contact-view'
});

App.contactsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    initData: function(data) {
        var contacts = data.map(function(contact) {
            return App.Contact.create({
                "name": contact.name,
                "avatar": contact.avatar
            });
        });
        this.pushObjects(contacts);
    },

    pair: (function() {
        content = this.get('content');
        var result = [];
        for (ii = 0; ii < content.length; ii += 2) {
            result.pushObject({
                "first": content[ii],
                "second": content[ii + 1] ? content[ii + 1] : null
            });
        }
        return result;
    }).property('content')
});

App.contactsController.initData([{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "avatar": "/john.jpg"},
{
    "name": "Someone Else",
    "avatar": "/else.jpg"}]);​
```

Comment: Does it have something to see with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8526070/90741 ?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example? Maybe a JSFiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't manage to run it. I hope you get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Zm4Xg/5/

Comment: Ahh, whoops, I probably shouldn't have put pseudo-code inside curly-braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```html
{{#each App.myController.content}}
    {{view MyView contentBinding="content.first"}}
    {{view MyView contentBinding="content.second"}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Inside your `MyView`, you have to reference the values via `content.name`. See http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/TjK8H/

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I need. However, even if I copy your code and use in my project, it does not work. What could be the problem? (Your jsfiddle works).

Comment: @PavelS. I don't know, basically I just changed the template and added the `contentBinding`... http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/UugXn/

Comment: Well, the problem was following: I have defined ENV variables CP_DEFAULT_CACHEABLE: true and VIEW_PRESERVES_CONTEXT: true. Then, I had to use view.content.attribute to get to the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the View class with a ***templateName*** function that evaluates to a different view based on a property of the model, like this:

```
App.customView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:function(){     
          if(this.get('content').get('index') === 1){
            return 'view1';
          }
          else{
            return 'view2';                               
          }
    }.property('content.index') // custom template function based on 'index' property
});
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lifeinafolder/7hnc9/

Comment: I edited the question. The point is I need to pass first and second variables to the same view. In other words, I have one view which I want to use twice.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont understand your comment. If you want to use the same view, then just have a single template and templateName could be a string instead of a function.

Comment: Please, have a look at my jsfiddle. It does not run but you may get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Zm4Xg/5/